# greenplum hang forever when doing any search or insert actions with psql and centos7

Tags: centos7, freeze, greenplum

greenplum version is 5.3.0  centos 7

As title, 
The following is  result of gplogfilter

```
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,7)='test_vb' AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,7) = substring('test_vb',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) > 1
UNION
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid AND c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v' , 'x') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,7)='test_vb' AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,7) = substring('test_vb',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname))+1) AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,7) = substring('test_vb',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) = 1
LIMIT 1000|0||postgres.c|1629|
2018-01-02 12:21:20.685964 UTC|||p20871|th-636074112||||0|||seg-1|||||LOG: |00000|3rd party error log:
Unexpected exception reached top of execution stack: major=200 minor=14 file=CTranslatorUtils.cpp line=162||||||||SysLoggerMain|syslogger.c|633|
2018-01-02 12:21:20.686005 UTC|gpadmin|testdb|p21604|th-636074112|[local]||2018-01-02 12:13:41 UTC|0|con8|cmd4|seg-1||dx22||sx1|LOG: |00000|Planner produced plan :0||||||SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v' , 'x') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,7)='test_vb' AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) AND c.relnamespace <> (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'pg_catalog')
UNION
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,7)='test_vb' AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,7) = substring('test_vb',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) > 1
UNION
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid AND c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v' , 'x') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,7)='test_vb' AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,7) = substring('test_vb',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname))+1) AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,7) = substring('test_vb',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) = 1
LIMIT 1000|0||orca.c|60|
2018-01-02 12:21:22.351554 UTC|gpadmin|testdb|p21604|th-636074112|[local]||2018-01-02 12:13:41 UTC|0|con8|cmd6|seg-1||dx23||sx1|LOG: |00000|statement: SELECT * FROM test_vb;||||||SELECT * FROM test_vb;|0||postgres.c|1629|
       in:      77 lines; timestamps from 2018-01-02 11:31:19.698317 to 2018-01-02 12:21:22.351554
      out:      77 lines; timestamps from 2018-01-02 11:31:19.698317 to 2018-01-02 12:21:22.351554
----------  /data/master/gpseg-1/pg_log/gp_era ----------
# Greenplum Database era.
# Do not change the contents of this file.
era = 27c9a01176c70c2c_180102113109
       in:       3 lines; no timestamps found
      out:       3 lines
```

Comment: You should probably add if this is open source or not.  Describe the nodes, segments per host, other activity, etc.  Have you analyzed the catalog yet?  Or ran reindex on the catalog?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of CentOS 7 are you using?   There are known problems with RHEL/CentOS 7.0-7.2 (see Greenplum release notes).  You should be using 7.3 or 7.4 - there were kernel problems in the early version 7 of the OS that were fixed in 7.3/4.

Jim McCann
Pivotal

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Linux tp-gpdb-ku02.novalocal 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: p.s. I don't have firewall,standby host, and mirror doesn't be set yet.

Comment: Even I reinstall greenplum, it has the same problem

Comment: 1 master and 3 segments with 4CPU/8G/100G

Comment: The database is new-build, and the occupied space of memory and disk are low

Comment: After hours of waiting it produces error
ERROR:  Interconnect encountered a network error, please check your network  (seg0 slice1 172.21.140.46:40000 pid=14733)
DETAIL:  Failed to send packet (seq 1) to 172.21.140.17:2938 (pid 1465 cid -1) after 3577 retries in 3600 seconds
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select sum(gp_statistics_estimate_reltuples_relpages_oid(c.oid))::float4[] from gp_dist_random('pg_class') c where c.oid=16387"

Comment: I found the reason:  packets lose unexpectedly .  I set gp_interconnect_type tcp, it works, but I don't know why packets lose.

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum uses TCP connection when starting to active database and tell Segments the address of Master and other operations on database are with UDP connection and master address is got from prior TCP connection.  The problem is that the segment only get the modified address of master and try to send messages to modified address if master uses NAT method. Then one of the solve method is to tell segment the address when master send queries by modifying the value of proc->listenerAddr   in source code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue while selecting and inserting but Teddy's last comment worked for me i.e. enable UDP protocol for all hosts (master as well segment).
So for greenplum few protocol needs to be enable TCP, UDP, SSH, ICMP.